# Run a macro specific to sheet A from any sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in Sheet A. It is running fine when I'm in sheet A but when I'm trying to run it from sheet B, it throws an error.

```
Sub BP_Clear()
    Dim Lastrow_Data1 As Long
    Dim Lastrow_Pivot1 As Long

    Lastrow_Data1 = Sheets("A").Range("G20000").End(xlUp).row
    Lastrow_Pivot1 = Sheets("A").Range("B20000").End(xlUp).row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("G10").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Cells(10, 7), Cells(Lastrow_Pivot1 + 10000, 7)).ClearContents

    Application.CutCopyMode = False     
End Sub
```

Comment: When you run this on sheet B, you want it to work on sheet B or sheet A? You have fixed it to work on sheet A...

Comment: I want the macro to work on Sheet A only even if I run it from any other sheet.

Comment: Why don't you add a module and specify the sheet you want the macro to work on?

Comment: Hi, the issue is resolved. I was making a silly mistake. Thanks all for your help.